# Cloned Prod Web & Database Server to create staging, what next?

Tags: database, core-config-data, staging

I am trying to correctly setup a Staging environment. I cloned both my Production Web Server and Production Database Server to replicate both in a Staging setting with their own separate droplets (virtual servers), but now I am lost.

How do I get the Staging Web server (right now is identical to prod) to look at the Staging Database server (also is identical to prod)?

Any other changes I need to make to them?

Apologies I am very new to DBA & Magento.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to indentify Staging Server:

1. **Database Names:**

Did you create the staging database from scratch and imported your live database to the staging then you must have had a different database name for staging.

2. **Core-Config-Data in PHPMYADMIN**

Core-Config-Data Check for base urls in your core-config-data if you have previously set those they should tell you which database you are in.

3. **FTP Public HTML**

Go to your html directory via Filezilla/CyberDuck or any FTP client and click public html folder, this will automatically expand your live file system, so now you know your live file system.

If you are confused take a backup of your staging files & delete the non-public-html files and folders.